# SwiftUI parse a json from an URL with entry values

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm stuck when a I need to load a json file to swiftUI when this json comes from an URL with entry variables that must be filled by the user before getting the data.
I have the following code:

```
// This is the structure to get the data from the API.

struct loka_result: Codable {
    var date: String
    var time: String
    var unix_time: Int
    var seqNumber : Int
    var lat: Double
    var lng: Double
    var device: String
    var accuracy: Double
    var info: String
    var temperature : Double?
    var battery_voltage : Float?
}


// Now conform to Identifiable
extension loka_result: Identifiable {
    public var id: Int { return unix_time }
}

// Model Data to get the data

final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var allthelokas : [loka_result] = loadAllData(deviceId:selected_loka, timeDelta: selected_delta)
    
}

// Function to get and parse the data

func loadAllData<T: Decodable>(deviceId:String,timeDelta:Int) -> T

{
    
let url = URL(string: "https://xxxx.php?device=\(deviceId)&hours=\(timeDelta)"),
    data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    return
        try! JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!)
}
```

Then in TempChartView I would like to get a list

```
import SwiftUI

struct TempChartNew: View {
    
    
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            List(modelData.allthelokas) { j in
               // ForEach(modelData.allthelokas) { jj in
                    HStack {
                        Text(j.device)
                        Text(j.date)
                        Text(j.time)
                        Text(String(j.seqNumber))
                    }
                    
               
 
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TempChartNew_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TempChartNew().environmentObject(ModelData())
      
    }
}
```

all this its working because just to test it I have added two global variables to fill in the data for the function.

```
var selected_loka: String = "3JJJ30"
var selected_delta: Int = 24
```

But the ideia would be for the view to have two entry points.
And its here where I'm stuck ! I don't know how to pass the variables to the class.
Does anyone can please point me in the correct direction ? - Thank you

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from loading data synchronously from a remote URL with `Data(contentsOf:`. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata): **Important:** *Don't use this synchronous initializer to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.*

Comment: Thank you @vadian.I will change it to async fetch based in your comment I already have the class that does it that way. But building that fetch class that has the above url still leaves me stuck since I don't know how to trigger that async fetch based in user inputs that changes the url query.